# How to configure Application Pool with MSDeploy

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy

I'm currently using MSBuild to create an MSDeploy package by passing in arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Package
```

I'm using a parameters.xml file (placed at the root of my website).  [Another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241314/how-to-specify-default-application-pool-in-asp-net-mvc-project/12630846#comment18634094_12630846) I found tries to set up the application pool.

My parameters.xml file:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="Application Pool Name" description="Application Pool for this site" tags="" defaultValue="ASP.NET v4.0">
        <parameterEntry kind="DeploymentObjectAttribute"
                        scope="application"
                        match="/application/@applicationPool" />
    </parameter>
...
</parameters>
```

but it seems that the archive.xml file inside the msdeploy package generated by the msbuild doesn't have an  section with an applicationPool element

How can I get the archive.xml to be generated with this section so that I can set the application pool?

The app pool I want to set will exist already, so I'm not concerned with MSDeploy synching or creating app pools here.

Edit:
I have found this question [How do I control the AppPool used for deploy through VS & MSDeploy settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690954/how-do-i-control-the-apppool-used-for-deploy-through-vs-msdeploy-settings) which hints at using wpp.targets to generate a custom provider.  I'm exploring how to use this approach to modify the archive.xml file

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have the correct IIS settings on your project and are running as Administrator, you should be able to specify `IncludeIisSettings=true` to have the settings included in the zip.

If you need the actual AppPool definition included (so it can be created), you should also set `IncludeAppPool=true`.

Comment: Where do you specify these settings?

Comment: @reggaeguitar: Either in a `PropertyGroup` element in your `pubxml` file, or as a command line argument to MSDeploy using `/p:Property=value`

Comment: when include these parameters, I got error MSB4044: The "EscapeTextForRegularExpressions" task was not given a value for the required parameter "Text".  when try build