# Can I web deploy to specific app pool

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

**Update**
Alright, I've done more research and I'm getting closer.

I specified the application pool in the parameters file but it's still going to wrong pool?

[image]

**Original Post**
I'm in Visual Studio 2012 and would like to know if there is a way to specify which app pool is desired when using web deploy for publishing my web site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure Application Pool with MSDeploy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594670/how-to-configure-application-pool-with-msdeploy)